# How can I get a rect with just two of the corners rounded?

Tags: svg

I'm thinking about adding rounded corners to my Bar chart - but only the top two corners. However the SVG rx and ry attributes to the  tag round all of the corners.

So is there a way to do this with the  tag or should I just use the  tag instead?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use a <`rect>`. You have to make your own rounded rectangle with a `<path>`.

Comment: Alrighty. Thanks.